# Is this a Liskov Substitution Principle violation?

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

My custom button is actually a button, so is it violating the LSP?

```
class ConditionalButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Condition())
            base.OnClick(e);
    }
    private bool Condition()
    {
        //return true or false
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it violates LSP. But I bet it violates user interface guidelines. If `Condition()` is `False`,  disable the button so that it cannot be pressed.

Comment: @JackHughes I agree with your second point(user interface guidelines) and disagree with first one as this is clearly LSP violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this **does** violate LSP. Please refer Object Mentor simplified definition of The Liskov Substitution Principle from [Object Mentor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf) article:

> “Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it.”

It would seem it is ok as we can use `ConditionalButton` as a `Button` from this point of view. But:

> In order for the LSP to hold, and with it the Open-Closed principle, all derivatives
>   must conform to the behavior that clients expect of the base classes that they use

and for sure clients expect that after clicking a button, `OnClick` will be executed.

Moreover, from the same article:

> ...when redefining a routine [in a derivative], you may only replace its
>   precondition by a weaker one, and its postcondition by a stronger one.

In my opinion, `ConditionalButton` Violates LSP in current form, because `Condition` allows to click a button, while logic related with button won't be executed. If `Condition` would be related with enabled/disabled flag - it would not violate LSP.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think this is the most complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a strengthening of preconditions in the subtype. A clear violation of LSP.

I.e.

Button says:

> As long as the button is enabled, on click do some work

ConditionalButton says:

> As long as the button is enabled **and Condition() is true**, on click do some work

Comment: @Flavius my answer was all about LSP?!

Comment: @Flavius "I wouldn't just ignore a click" Well your code does. I can't comment on code you haven't provided.

Comment: @weston Thanks for the answer, you have my upvote anyway. There was some misunderstanding regarding how to respect the user interface guidelines.